# Custom HTML5 video controls - Display mute button only

Tags: jquery, css, html, html5-video

Can I somehow edit the HTML5 video controls to only display the mute/unmute button and in the top right hand corner of my video? I have found a way to do so but I'm choosing to "display: none;" in the CSS for all other ids and buttons (which isn't the best way to accomplish this). Also, it works but the only browser it works in is Chrome. 
http://jsfiddle.net/pp6Wn/2/

```
<div id="video-container">
<video id="my_video" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <source src="http://romain-menard.fr/cours_html5/sitedemo/src/small.mp4"
    type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="video/movie.webm"
    type="video/webm" />
     </video>
<!-- Video Controls -->
<div id="video_controls_bar">
    <button id="playpausebtn"></button>

    <span id="curtimetext">00:00</span>
    <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1"><span id="durtimetext">00:00</span>
    <button id="mutebtn">Mute</button>
    <input id="volumeslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
    <button id="fullscreenbtn"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to create another button,
add some CSS to it, and assign the JS mute function:

**HTML:**
Create a new button and place it into the "video-continer" div, but **out** of "video_controls_bar" div:

```
    </video>
<button id="mutebtn2">Mute</button>
<!-- Video Controls -->
<div id="video_controls_bar">
```

**JS:**
Assign the mute function:
in the JS file add this two lines to the "initializePlayer()" function:

```
mutebtn2 = document.getElementById("mutebtn2");
mutebtn2.addEventListener("click",vidmute2,false);
```

and then add this new function:

```
function vidmute2(){
    if(vid.muted){
        vid.muted = false;
        mutebtn2.innerHTML = "Mute";
    } else {
        vid.muted = true;
        mutebtn2.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    }
}
```

**CSS:**
Add css style to place the new button to the video top-right corner:

```
#mutebtn2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

And if you want to hide video controls, in the css file just change this:

```
#video-container:hover #video_controls_bar {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

to this:

```
/* this is just a CSS comment, you can bypass it */
/* #video-container:hover #video_controls_bar {
    opacity: 1;
} */
```

---

[image: jsFiddle]